# Custom wysiwyg editor doesn't execute shortcodes?

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, editor, wysiwyg

I encounter this weird problem.. I'm trying to create a simple & easy website for a client. He wants to embed video's into the page.

I use different customfields assigned to specific elements in the website. I hide the standard wordpress wysiwyg editor and registred a new one to put it in line with other customfields.

Here is the problem, when i use the shortcode icons made by plugins and i post them in the registered wysiwyg editor and i save the page, it doesn't work, it only shows the short-code.

Example short-code:

```
[pro-player width='600' height='600' type='video']http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nOjUXGCREs[/pro-player]
```

But when i use the short-code in the original wordpress wysiwyg editor it does execute it properly.

Ofcourse when i call the plugins short-code throughout a .PHP file it definitely works.. But i want to keep it easy & simple for the client to understand, so an generated icon would be my best bet.

Why does he custommade wysiwyg editor execute short-codes as text ?

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Greetz

Comment: You're aware of oembed? Simply paste a youtube URL on its own line, making sure it isnt turned into a hyperlink, and itll be replaced with a full youtube embed on the frontend. Apply CSS styling to the embed so it fits correctly

Comment: Thanks for the response, strangely It doesn't work on a custom made wysiwyg editor... I tried it on the standard wordpress editor and it works....

Comment: How is this *custom made WYSIWYG editor* made?

Comment: Yes you have a problem with your code yet no code is provided

Comment: I use custom metaboxes & fields for wordpress.  https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress, Its kinda strange that i can't find much information about this problem..

Comment: @Tom , i only register the wysiwyg editor via :   $meta_boxes[] = array(
'id'         => 'content_invoervelden',
'title'      => 'Content',
'pages'      => array( 'page'), // Post type
'context'    => 'normal',
'priority'   => 'high',
'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
'fields'     => array(
 array(
 'pages' => array('page'), // post type
 'context' => 'normal',
 'priority' => 'high',
 'name'    => 'Teksten toevoegen',
 'desc'    => 'Voeg de teksten van de pagina toe',
 'id'      => $prefix . 'content_inhoud',
 'type'    => 'wysiwyg',
 ),
    ),
);

Comment: can you post that as an answer not a comment?

Answer (score 7):

Yessss, I fixed the problem, i needed to apply a filter into the get_post_meta to make it work.

```
<?php  echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wenc_content_inhoud', true)); ?>
```

Thanks anyway!